# what is the correct shahada in Islam?

Tags: islamic-basis, shahada

I am really confused. What is the correct way of saying shahada. Ashadu all or Ashadu an la. Please answer with some evidence ASAP. I mean what is the begiining. Ashadu an la or ashadu al

Comment: Click on the corresponding tag and check related answers and then come back if none of them is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

اشهد أن لا اله الا الله

Here in اب لا you don't spell the consonant ب because it is followed by ل due to the arabic grammar rule الغام (Ilgam).

Ilgam is a rule in which you don't spell consonant ن if it is followed by certain letters.

Edit:

So the correct way to say is "Ashhadu al la" not "Ashhadu an la"

Comment: So, i pronounce it as Ashadu all right?

Comment: @sohailMir yes, I'm sorry I was in a rush so I didn't type in the way to correctly pronounce it